# Count posts returned by get_posts in external PHP script

Tags: wp-query, get-posts, api

I'm using WP from an external PHP script by including the `wp-load.php` file.

All functions and everything works as expected so far, except one thing: I can't get the `$wp_query->found_posts` to work after I fetch posts with `get_posts()` function.

Any hints what should I be using instead?

Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

The WordPress function `get_posts()` is making it's own instance of `WP_Query` that is not globally accessible:

```
function get_posts($args = null) {
    // ... cut ...
    $get_posts = new WP_Query;
    return $get_posts->query($r);
}
```

so you could instead try

```
 $results = get_posts($args);
 echo count($results);
```

to give you the array count of post objects returned by `get_posts()`.

### WP_Query() class usage example:

You could consider using the `WP_Query()` class directly.

Here is an example how you can use it:

```
<?php
// your input parameters:   
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 10,
);

$my_query = new WP_Query( $args );?>

Found posts: <?php echo $my_query->found_posts;?>

<?php if ( $my_query->have_posts() ):?>
    <ul>
        <?php while ( $my_query->have_posts() ) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>
            <li> <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
    </ul>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php wp_reset_postdata();?>
```

We use `wp_reset_postdata()` in the end, to restore the global `$post` object, since we change it via `the_post()` method.

### Reference:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_reset_postdata

http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However that won't really work - the `get_posts()` will return the number of items per page I determine. If there are 100 posts in total and I fetch 10, counting the results like this will still give me 10. Hope this makes sense.

Comment: Dirty solution would be to run the query twice, with `numberposts` parameter set to `-1` and count these results. But it's horrible from performance point of view and I doubt this is the correct solution.

Comment: What about using WP_Query instead of get_posts?

Comment: Will give it a try. Should I use again the `$wp_query->found_posts` to get the count of all results?

Comment: you should use something else than `$wp_query`, for example `$my_query = new WP_Query($args);` and then `$my_query->found_posts` and remember to use `wp_reset_postdata()` in the end if you change the global `$post` object.

Comment: I updated the answer.